# concept of trilinear interpolation.

Tags: interpolation

I have a big confusing about trilinear interpolation.
first, Interpolation's concept is estimating between two points(I'll call it as start point and end point), right?

and this is depiction of trilinear interpolation from wikipedia.

[image]

It has 8 input, like C00,C001,...,C111. but Basically, Interpolation's input gonna be two(start pnt, end pnt) isn't it?
Then, I have to make vector between two point, and project it on x,y,z axis,
and make the 8 input from that? If my suppose is right, c00 is start point and c111 point is end. but I don't think so.
Trilinear is linear interpolation in 3d, but I can't apply it to the points as [1,0,2] and [4,3,1]. ( [1,0,2] : start, [4,3,1] : end )
help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the start and end point that you mention, you could get away with an interpolation along only the connecting line (1D)... For the whole 3D space, you would need atleast 4 non-coplanar points.

Comment: then, you mean, I don't need to any dot product like projection when I interpolate, right?